# Why cant you push_back in 2D vector? c++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, 2d, push-back

I am learning recursion in c++ and was stuck on why you cant simply use the `.push_back()` instead of creating a function to copy the `specific_previous_result` elements, then `.push_back()`.

```
vector<vector<int>> get_every_n_elements(vector<int> arr, int n) {
if (n == 0) {
    vector<vector<int>> result;

    vector<int> empty_list;
    result.push_back(empty_list);

    return result;
}

vector<vector<int>> previous_result = get_every_n_elements(arr, n - 1);

vector<vector<int>> current_result; //empty

for (auto specific_previous_result : previous_result) { // [[]] -> []

    for (auto elem : arr) { // [1,2,3,4] -> 1
      //current_result.push_back(specific_previous_result.push_back(elem));
      //This does not work^^

      current_result.push_back(group(specific_previous_result, elem));
      //The group function copies all elements to newVec and push_back(elem) after
      //Then returns newVec with elem at the end
    }

}

return current_result;
}
```

The error that I get when I run the push_back line is `error: invalid use of void expression current_result.push_back(specific_previous_result.push_back(elem));`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: even if it did work it would do what you expect, because `specific_previous_result` is a copy of the vector, you want `for (auto& specific_previous_result : previous_result)` instead

Comment: and what is that line supposed to mean anyhow? You are trying to push the return value of another `push_back`, but `push_back` returns `void`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a valid reason to return the vector itself after a `push_back`. Sometimes it's useful, but most of the time, it is not. I would recommend writing it in two lines, which is also more clearer IMO than a separate (and inefficient!) function:

```
current_result.push_back(specific_previous_result);
current_result.back().push_back(elem);
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why that line is causing the compiler to give you the `invalid use of void expression current_result.push_back(specific_previous_result.push_back(elem));` error is trivial.  Take a look at the line in question:

`current_result.push_back(`**specific_previous_result.push_back(elem)**`);`

The bolded part is calling the vector's `push_back` function, a function which has a `void` return type.  You are attempting to pass this `void` return value as a parameter to `current_result.push_back`.

[See the documentation for `std::vector::push_back`.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)  As you can see, the return value for both overloads is `void`.

You said it yourself, your `group` function is **returning a vector** which you are then pushing onto the back of your `current_result` vector.  This is why the line which uses the `group` function compiles.

Comment: O I see, I did not know that `std::vector::push_back` returned void. I am coming from Python and was under the impression it returned a copy of the vector with the new element appended to the end.